# How to avoid memory leaks while using Subject

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, behaviorsubject

Here, I'm establishing an observable, and upon a click event, I'm unsubscribing from it. While this action successfully unsubscribes from the observable and clears the interval when using Observable, if I opt for a Subject, the anonymous function generated during the creation of the observable doesn't execute. This leads to a memory leak. How to handle such scenarios?

```
    let newObs = new Observable<number>(observer=>{
      let i=0;
      let interval = setInterval((f:any)=>{
        i++;
        console.log(i+"in observer");
        observer.next(i)
      },1000)

      return ()=>{
        console.log("will be executed when unsubscribed or on error");
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
    })

    let sub = new Subject<number>();
    newObs.subscribe(sub);
    this.subscription2 = sub.subscribe({
      next: (data: number) => { console.log(data+" subscription2") },
      error: (error: string) => { console.log(error) },
      complete: ()=>{console.log('complete')}
    })

    this.subscription = sub.subscribe(f=>{
      console.log(f+"in subscription");
    },error=>{
      console.log(error)
    },()=>{
      console.log("complete")
    })
```

to unsubscribe subscriptions on click

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
    fromEvent(this.mapm.nativeElement,'click').subscribe(res=>{
      console.log(res)
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
      this.subscription2.unsubscribe();
    },(error:any)=>{
      console.log(error)
    },()=>{
      console.log("completed!")
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sames goes for your click handler, in case the user does not click the element. In both cases you can use the `takeUntilDestroyed()` operator:

```ts
observable$.pipe(takeUntilDestroyed()).subscribe(...);
```

This will automatically unsubscribe when the component is destroyed.

In case it's not used in a constructor context, you need to provide a `DestroyRef`:

```ts
private destroyRef = inject(DestroyRef);
...
observable$.pipe(takeUntilDestroyed(this.destroyRef)).subscribe(...);
```

For Angular versions < 16 you can use a custom Subject that emits and complets in `ngOnDestroy` with `takeUntil`:

```ts
private destroy$ = new Subject<void>();
...
observable$.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe(...);
...
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.destroy$.next();
  this.destroy$.complete();
}
```

Comment: DestroyRef is introduced in Angular 16, is there any option for below versions?

Comment: Added a section for older versions in above.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are not unsubscribing the subscription you should unsubscribe.

In other words, to stop the stream, you should do the following

```
// fist store the subscription to newObs in a variable
const subscription0 = newObs.subscribe(sub);

// then, at the click of the button, you should unsubscribe such subscription
subscription0.unsubscribe()
```

If you do so, you stop the upstream represented by `newObs` (i.e. the real source of the stream) and you do not need to unsubscribe the other subscriptions, unless there are other reasons.

Here a simple [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-19g3jz?file=index.ts).